# SMTP Email Error

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am using Visual Studio 2010. I am trying to send an email to 1 email address when the user hits submit. I am getting the error below:

Error: Syntax error, command unrecognized. The server response was: 5.0.0 Your email system must authenticate before sending mail:

Here is my code in my code behind:

```
public void SendMail(string FromEmail, string ToEmail, string Subject, string Body)
    {
        System.Net.Mail.MailMessage eMail = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
        eMail.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress(FromEmail);
        //MailMessage eMail = new MailMessage();
        //eMail.From = new MailAddress(FromEmail);
        eMail.To.Add(ToEmail);
        eMail.Subject = Subject;
        eMail.IsBodyHtml = true;
        eMail.Body = Body;
        SmtpClient SMTP = new SmtpClient();
        //SMTP.Host = "mail.authsmtp.com";
        //SMTP.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        //SMTP.EnableSsl = true;
        SMTP.Send(eMail);
        eMail.Dispose();
    } 




protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

   StringBuilder sbBody = new StringBuilder();
                string FromEmail = "smit@college.edu";
                string ToEmail = "smit@college.edu";
                string Subject = "Application for" + " " + txtFirstName.Text + " " + txtLastName.Text + " " + "created on:" + " " + txtDateCreated.Text;
                sbBody.Append("Click link below to view application for" + " " + txtFirstName.Text + " " + txtLastName.Text);
                sbBody.Append("<br/>");
                sbBody.Append("<br/>");
                sbBody.Append("AdminDisplay.aspx?ID=@ID");
                sbBody.Append("<br/>");
                sbBody.Append("Thank you,");
                sbBody.Append("Admin");
                SendMail(FromEmail, ToEmail, Subject, sbBody.ToString());  

            }
```

Here is my web.config:

```
<system.net>
        <mailSettings>
            <smtp from="smit@college.edu">
                <network host="mail.authsmtp.com" defaultCredentials="true" />
            </smtp>
        </mailSettings>
    </system.net>
```

I have been working on this most of the day and need to get it working. Thank you

Comment: Are you using Exchange? I know that our Exchange administrator has to enable PCs and servers for email sending. I'm sorry I can't be more specific - I know nothing about Exchange.

Comment: Your SMTP server may also require credentials. Check with whoever set it up.